# Loading data from rss feed?

Tags: android

I want to have a rss string set to a variable. i want the content to be loaded inside the application when the list item is clicked which is holding the rss feedlable("Example new Feed" in the list).

How do i go about doing this to create a listview of strings of rss feeds with Labels for the feed it is, and then when it is clicked load the content in another activity?

A example would be greate!

Answer (score 1):

There is a great tutorial on RSS parsing at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html

It also has a lot of source code as well. If you want an introductory tutorial, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-androidrss/ might help you